# "Unknown name "": must be root element." error with Node.js Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I'm using a discord bot to read/write information to a single Google Spreadsheet, thus I've been trying to learn the poorly documented Spreadsheet API. I've already figured out how to append, read, and delete rows one by one. I'm trying to edit a row by changing it's cell values to the values in `vals[1]`.

This uses Google Spreadsheets API v4 and Node.js v10.13.0. This `sheets.spreadsheets.update` method structure was copied directly from Google's Node.js examples. I've only inserted my own values for all the parameters, of course. I've already looked everywhere for the specific kind of error I'm getting. I've also double checked with the API about what could possibly be wrong.

```
vals = [number, [cell1, cell2, undefined]];
sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
  spreadsheetId: config.spreadsheet,
  range: sheetNames[sheet] + '!A' + vals[0] + ':B',
  resource: vals[1],
  valueInputOption: 'RAW',
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    message.channel.send('**Successful `edit` request!**')
    //other code
  }
});
```

Obviously, the code is throwing an error with the request. It should go through smoothly down to the "successful edit request" message.

```
{ Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a message.
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> ( [other files]/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:73:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled ([other files] /Personal Projects/siracha/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:16:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: There's too many unknown values here to help. What is `number`, `cell1`, `cell2`, `sheetNames` and `sheet`?

Comment: First thing that stands out is the [documentation example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) for `resource` shows an object but you are passing it an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to put the values using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to put and get values using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please use an object for `resource` and use 2 dimensional array for `values`

#### From:

```
resource: vals[1],
```

#### To:

```
resource: {values: [vals[1]]},
```

#### Note:

- In your values, I think that you can use `range: sheetNames[sheet] + "!A" + vals[0],` instead of `range: sheetNames[sheet] + "!A" + vals[0] + ":B",`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

If this was not the solution, I apologize.

Comment: Glad I found this answer first.